# Assembly: Difference between declaration with ' ' and without it

Tags: assembly, x86, character

I'm a beginner in Assembly language. I want to know the difference between a declaration enclosed with ' ' and without it.

For example,

variable1 db '0'

variable2 db 0

I know that the one with '' is when printed, it will show what's inside the ''.

Thanks! :)

Comment: One question per question please. See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single quotes it's an ASCII character, without quotes it's just an integer value:

```
v1 db '0'    ; ASCII character '0' = 0x30 
v2 db 'A'    ; ASCII character 'A' = 0x41 

v3 db 0      ; integer value 0 = 0x00
v4 db 9      ; integer value 9 = 0x09
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So the one with ' ' is in hex while without is in decimal.
Sorry about my mistake. I didn't know that. I just add it because I thought it is quite related. I need to make another thread for the other question, right?

Comment: Note quite - I've added more examples to the answer to hopefully make it clearer. And yes, if you have a second question then post is separately as a new question.